# Giving error "the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes' "

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I was following a tutorial that how to use elasticsearch with python (link= 
  https://tryolabs.com/blog/2015/02/17/python-elasticsearch-first-steps/#contacto) i faced this error.

```
import json
    r = requests.get('http://localhost:9200') 
    i = 1
    while r.status_code == 200:
        r = requests.get('http://swapi.co/api/people/'+ str(i))
        es.index(index='sw', doc_type='people', id=i, body=json.loads(r.content))
        i=i+1

    print(i)
```

TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'

Answer (score 8):

You are using Python 3, and the blog post is aimed at Python 2 instead. The Python 3 `json.loads()` function expects decoded *unicode text*, not the raw response bytestring, which is what `response.content` returns.

Rather than use `json.loads()`, leave it to `requests` to decode the JSON correctly *for you*, by using the `response.json()` method:

```
es.index(index='sw', doc_type='people', id=i, body=r.json())
```